# TypeError: response.status is not a function at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/signup/route.js:19:25)

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, routes

```
//route.js
import {connect} from "@/dbConnection/dbConnection";
import User from "@/models/userModel";
connect();
export async function POST(request, response) {
    try {
        const {username, email, password} = await request.json();
        console.log(username, email, password);
        return response.status(201).json({message: "User created successfully"});
    }catch (e){
        return response.status(500).json({message: "Error creating user",
        error: e.message
        });
    }
}
```

I am building an next.js app and while making an route i am getting this error:

```
error = `"" TypeError: response.status is not a function
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/signup/route.js:19:25) ""`
```

As I am building it using js only, I cannot define types in the function. It will throw syntax error.

I tried to define types but got syntax error.

Comment: This isn't a type hinting issue. It's saying that `status` isn't a function. Check what it is. I'm guessing `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the App router, the second parameter of route handler is the event not the response.

To send a response you can use the built-in `Response` API or import the `NextResponse` class from `"next/server"`;

```js
//route.js
import {connect} from "@/dbConnection/dbConnection";
import User from "@/models/userModel";
connect();
export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        const {username, email, password} = await request.json();
        console.log(username, email, password);

        return Response.json({message: "User created successfully"}, { status: 201 });

    }catch (e){
        return Response.json({message: "Error creating user",
        error: e.message
        }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

Or

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

// ...

return NextResponse.json({ message: "success" }, { status: 201 })
```